# Looking for a ~300 degree/sec gyro

Tags: gyro

I was going to use the LY330 or the LY530 from ST Microelectronics and they should do the job very well. However, due to the stupid US Export Restrictions, Digikey won't sell any to me (I live in Australia).

Are there any recommended gyroscopes that I can buy (Z-axis) that are easily sourced (no export restrictions from digikey), offer ranges of at least 300 deg/sec (don't care if it is digital or analogue), and are highly accurate?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why won't Digikey sell to Australia on export regulations?? Is an accelerometer considered military equipment or something?

Comment: They are told that stuff.

Comment: @ThomasO  Gyros can be used to make an inertial measurement unit (IMU), which can be an important part if a guided weapon (like JDAM) or a UAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Invensense](http://invensense.com/index.html). They have a nice range of gyroscopes and seem to sell directly from their site. Don't know about export restrictions though.

If it is only for a single project or a prototype, you can always try to gut a Wii motionplus for its part: the invensense [IDG-600](http://www.dynacam3d.com/files/bibliographie/Wii-motion/IDG600_ProductBrief_English.pdf). Cheap motionplus modules can be found on [dealextreme](http://www.dealextreme.com/advsearch.dx/search.wii%20motionplus). [This one](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.32506) for instance, appears to have an [Invensense IDG-650](http://invensense.com/mems/gyro/idg650.html) which has a selectable range of 440 deg/s.

Comment: :( Shipping is 53 dollars from their store

Answer (score 0):

Mouser doesn't show these parts as being export controlled.

[LY330](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/LY330ALHTR/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvoxtwRLJtA572rnE0zh656)

[LY530](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/LY530ALH/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMthNezIpKscMTZnUFRtiwIe)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you order one from Element 14(Formerly Farnell) in Australia? Ive found the first part in their [system](http://au.element14.com/stmicroelectronics/ly330alh/gyroscope-mems-10lga/dp/1838548?Ntt=LY330).